# Can't click a button using selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click 'Login' button on the following url:
      [link]  https://exacttarget.com 
     Then, click Login and click marketing in cloud.

So far, i've tried the following and it didn't work:

1. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LoginForm']/div[4]/input[1]")).click();`
2. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='submit-btn']")).click();`

Can somebody help me out with this.

Thanks, Arpan.

```
<document>
<html class=" js backgroundsize" lang="en" data-placeholder-focus="false">
<head>
<body class="bb-bottom-color">
<!-- preloading images -->
<img style="display:none" alt="" src="/hub-cas/images/hero-image.png"/>
<img style="display:none" alt="" src="/hub-cas/images/hero-image-1.png"/>
<img style="display:none" alt="" src="/hub-cas/images/hero-image-2.png"/>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="login-header bb-top-color">
<div class="login-form-container bb-top-color clearfix" style="background-image: url("/hub-cas/images/hero-image-1.png");">
<form id="LoginForm" class="login-form" autocomplete="off" method="post" action="/hub- cas/login?wl=NiwzMDAzOTUzLGZlOTg1&service=https%3a%2f%2fimh.s6.exacttarget.com%2fhub%2f">
<input type="hidden" value="e1s1" name="lt"/>
<input id="loginEventId" type="hidden" value="submit" name="_eventId"/>
<div class="login-form-header clearfix">
<div id="jsBrowserDetectionTop" class="notification error" style="display:none"/>
<ul class="login-form-inputs formAttributes">
<div class="login-form-submit-container formAttributes">
<!-- Don't change the style name of the Login input (".submit-btn") without contacting       the Security team, as WebMetrics has a dependency on this value.Â  -->
<input class="submit-btn" type="submit" onclick="handleSubmit();" tabindex="4"        value="Login"/>
<input id="rememberMeChk" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" tabindex="3"/>
<label for="rememberMeChk">Remember Me</label>
<div class="forgot-pwd">
</div>
<div id="jsBrowserDetectionBottom" style="display:none"/>
<div class="secure-icon"/>
</form>
<div class="login-banner bb-hide">
</div>
<div class="login-footer bb-bottom-color"/>
</div>
<script src="/hub-cas/js/login.js?v=1.0.2" type="text/javascript"/>
</body>
</html>
</document>
```

Comment: [link](http:http://www.exacttarget.com/)

Comment: You've changed the link and now it doesn't seem to match up with your attempts at all. Please clarify the actual page you're using, or better yet, paste a snippet of HTML here

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"LOGIN"}

Comment: `code`  <form id="LoginForm" class="login-form" autocomplete="off" method="post" action="/hub-cas/login;jsessionid=8776264ABEFFA732AE6CDC3A8FA34F3D?service=https%3a%2f%2fimh.s6.exacttarget.com%2fhub%2f">
<input type="hidden" value="e1s1" name="lt"/>
<input id="loginEventId" type="hidden" value="submit" name="_eventId"/>
<div class="login-form-header clearfix">
<ul class="login-form-inputs formAttributes">
<div class="login-form-submit-container formAttributes">
<input class="submit-btn" type="submit" onclick="handleSubmit();" tabindex="4" value="Login"/>

Comment: This is either really badly formed HTML, or incomplete. Do those div's have end tags? Does the form have an end tag? Are there list items in that list & does the ul tag close nicely? From what I can see, there is no reason why the selectors I provided won't work, unless it's badly form HTML which the browser is not processing as you would expect

Comment: Just updated the html snippet. Do you see anything that might be stopping the script from clicking the 'Login' button.

Answer (score 0):

Best go with a CSS selector in this case IMO -

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#LoginForm .submit-btn")).click();
```

...or if you do want to use xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='LoginForm']//input[@class='submit-btn']")).click();
```

Comment: This didn't work either. I've added html snippet and exact error. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this should work,

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".submit-btn"))).click();
```

Comment: I get the following error:  org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"LOGIN"}

Comment: have edited the answer,the above statement worked for me in firefox 23.0

Answer (score 0):

I'am not good at java so i will write the code in python try to translate it.

```
options=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
for option in options:
     if option.text=="LOGIN":
     option.click()
time.sleep(2)
options=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
for option in options:
     if option.text=="Marketing Cloud (formerly IMH)":
     option.click()
```

The above code worked for me